# Correct way to specify a size of a React Component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I'm creating a React component that will display some data in a table. 
Since data are really a potentially big matrix, what I want is creating a sort of a viewport, and this require that my components has some way to specify its size.
Now I'm doing like this in the component usage:

```
<PivotGrid width="900" height="350"  dataSource={dataSource}></PivotGrid>
```

and internally in the component I'm doing like this:

```
    var sizeStyle = { 
                height:this.props.height+"px",
                width:this.props.width+"px"
            }
            return (
            <div style={sizeStyle} className={this.props.classes.pivotGridContainer}>
...
```

Is this an expected way of implementing such a functionality?

Comment: Yes, it is the expected way if you are not planning to change this width and height dynamically based on the window width/height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, I just like to do it like this

```
<PivotGrid width="900px" height="350px"  dataSource={dataSource}></PivotGrid>

class PivotGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      componentSize: {width: props.width,height: props.height}
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App" style={this.state.componentSize}>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ componentSize: { width: '400px', height: '200px'}})} >Change Component Size</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will work also in case in the future if you want to change the component size inside of the component

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend **styled-component** library for styling react components.

Your implementation would look like the following:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PivotGrid from './PivotGrid';

const PivotGridWrapper = styled(PivotGrid)`
  height: ${props => props.height}px;
  width: ${props => props.width}px;
`;

const component = (props) => (
  <PivotGridWrapper 
    dataSource={dataSource}
    height="350"  
    width="900" 
  />
)
```

Comment: JSS may do the job too.

Comment: Sure @DimaVishnyakov it can! My recommendation is based on the fact that JSS may be less clean to a large scale project. However, it can definitely work as well!

Answer (score 0):

Looks legit to me. You can put width and height directly into CSS class if you are using styled components or JSS. Also you can think about preventing component rerender when size props change.